# Creating a defaultdict of a tuple with a list and int

Tags: python-3.x, defaultdict

I know to create a `defaultdict` with default values, i can use the below:

```
defaultdict(lambda : 0)
```

and for a defaultdict of tuple with default values, i can use the following:

```
defaultdict(lambda: (0,0))
```

But i am struggling with this, how do i create a `defaultdict` of tuple with a list and an int? I need something like :

```
{key1:['a','b','c','a'],100),key2:(['a','a','a','a'],2100),(key3:['adds','bas','cs','a'],300),key4:(['a'],30)}
```

So i need to check for an item in the list, if it is not present, i need to increment the int value. Is my idea of tackling this situation using `defaultdict` correct??

Comment: you mean `defaultdict(lambda : [[],0])`? and BTW `defaultdict(lambda : 0)` can be written `defaultdict(int)`. I'm at a loss to understand your question here.

Comment: I used `defaultdict(lambda : [[],0])` and this was what i wanted. Thank you so much. Is this a good approach??As i explained earlier i need to update the int value in tuple based on the presence of an item in the list

Comment: that's not a tuple BTW or you wouldn't be able to update it. It's a list. approach is OK!

Comment: Can i make `defaultdict(lambda : [[],0])` something like `defaultdict(lambda : [set(),0])`??

Comment: Yes, i noticed it now!!That it is a list and not a tuple!!My bad!!Sorry!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to be able to do this:

```
d["some_key"][1] += 1
```

even if key doesn't exist and get `[set(),1]` as a value then do:

```
d = collections.defaultdict(lambda : [set(),0])
```

- Note #1: `defaultdict(lambda : 0)` is overkill for `defaultdict(int)`
- Note #2: I used a `list` and not a `tuple` for the default value. Had I used a `tuple`, I would have had a hard time to increment second item by 1 since tuples are read-only.
  Note #3: `tuple` is mostly useful as *keys* (because they're immutable, thus *hashable*), not as *values*, where you can store anything you want, hashable or not.